# Concurrency in Go loop polling case branch not hit

Tags: go, concurrency

I am implementing a very simple concurrent program in **Go**. There are 2 channels `todo` and `done` that are used for signaling which task is done. There are 5 `routines` that are executed and each one require its own time to complete. I would like to see every 100ms the status of what is happening.

However I tried but the polling branch `case <-time.After(100 * time.Millisecond):` seems that is never been called. It is called sometimes (not in a consisted way) if I reduce the time to something less than 100ms.

My understanding is that `go func` executes the method in a separate **Go** scheduler thread. I do not understand therefore why the `case` of the polling is never hit. I tried to move the specific case branch before/after the other but nothing changed.

Any suggestions?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func concurrent(id int, done chan int, todo chan int) {
    for {
        // doing a task
        t := randInt(50, 100)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(t) * time.Millisecond)
        done <- id
        // redo again this task
        t = randInt(50, 100)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(t) * time.Millisecond)
        todo <- id
    }
}

func randInt(min int, max int) int {
    return (min + rand.Intn(max-min))
}

func seedRandom() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
}

func main() {
    seedRandom()

    todo := make(chan int, 5)
    done := make(chan int, 5)

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        todo <- i
    }

    timeout := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        timeout <- true
    }()

    var mu sync.Mutex
    var output []int

loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(100 * time.Millisecond):
            //this branch is never hit?
            fmt.Printf("\nPolling status: %v\n", output)
        case <-timeout:
            fmt.Printf("\nDing ding, time is up!\n")
            break loop
        case id := <-done:
            mu.Lock()
            output = append(output, id)
            fmt.Printf(".") 
            mu.Unlock()
        case id := <-todo:
            go concurrent(id, done, todo)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** After following the answers I created this version in Go Playgound: https://play.golang.org/p/f08t984BdPt. That works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.After(100*time.Millisecond)` creates a brand new channel, with a brand new timer, which starts at the moment that function is called.

So, in your loop :

```golang
    for {
        select {
        // this statement resets the 100ms timer each time you execute the loop :
        case <-time.After(100*time.Millisecond):
            ...
```

Your branch never gets hit because, with 5 goroutines sending signals within less than 100ms on one of the other `case`s, this `time.After(100ms)` never reaches completion.

You need to choose a way to keep the same timer between iterations.

---

Here is one way to adapt your `time.After(...)` call :

```golang
    // store the timer in a variable *outside* the loop :
    statusTimer := time.After(100*time.Millisecond)

    for {
        select {
        case <-statusTimer:
            fmt.Printf("\nPolling status: %v\n", output)
            // reset the timer :
            statusTimer = time.After(100*time.Millisecond)
        case <-timeout:
            ...
```

---

Another way is, as @blackgreen suggests, to use a `time.Ticker` :

```golang
    statusTicker := time.NewTicker(100*time.Millisecond)

    for {
        select {
        case <-statusTicker.C:
            fmt.Printf("\nPolling status: %v\n", output)
        case <-timeout:
        ...
```

---

*side notes*

a. if the `output` slice is not shared with other goroutines, you don't need a mutex around its access :

```
   for {
      select {
      case <-statusTicker.C:
          fmt.Printf("\nPolling status: %v\n", output)
      ...
      case i <-done:
          // no race condition here : all happens within the same goroutine,
          // the 'select' statement makes sure that 'case's are executed
          // one at a time
          output = append(output, id)
          fmt.Printf(".")
```

b. For your `timeout` channel :

Another generic way to "signal" that some event occurred with a channel is to *close the channel* instead of sending a value on it :

```
   // if you don't actually care about the value you send over this channel :
   // you can make it unbuffered, and use the empty 'struct{}' type
   timeout := make(chan struct{})

   go func(){
       // wait for some condition ...
       <-time.After(1*time.Second)
       close(timeout)
   }()


   select {
   case <-statusTimer:
       ...
   case <-timeout: // this branch will also be taken once timeout is closed
       fmt.Printf("\nDing ding, time is up!\n")
       break loop
   case ...
```

The bug you will avoid is the following : suppose you want to use that `timeout` channel in *two* goroutines

- if you send a value over the timeout channel, only one goroutine will get signaled - it will "eat up" the value from the channel, and the other goroutine will only have a blocking channel,
- if you close the channel, both goroutines will correctly "receive" the signal

Answer (score 2):

you are creating 5 goroutines (func concurrent) and in your select case using the todo channel and this channel is being used in concurrent function so you end up creating a lot of goroutines

```
func concurrent(id int, done chan int, todo chan int) {
    for {
        // doing a task
        t := randInt(50, 100)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(t) * time.Millisecond)
        done <- id
        // redo again this task
        t = randInt(50, 100)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(t) * time.Millisecond)
        by doing this call you are re-crating the go-routime
        todo <- id
    }
}
```

when I ran your code I got "runtime.NumGoroutine()"
"number of goRoutines still running  347"

as you are implementing the time.After(100 * time.Millisecond) inside the for loop it gets reset every time some other case gets hit and in your case
case id := <-todo: && id := <-done: will always get hit within 100 Milliseconds that's why you didn't get the expected output (from how your code is now i would say that the number of go-routines would increase exponentially and each of em would be waiting to send value to done and few on todo channel so your loop wont get enough time(100 ms) to wait on time.After)

```
loop:
for {
    select {
    case <-time.After(100 * time.Millisecond): ->this will always get reset ( we can use time.Ticker as it will create a single object that will signal for each and every 100ms https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker
        //this branch is never hit?
        fmt.Printf("\nPolling status: %v\n", output)
    case <-timeout:
        fmt.Printf("\nDing ding, time is up!\n")
        break loop
    case id := <-done: -> **this will get called**  
        //the mutex call is actually not very usefull as this only get called once per loop and is prefectly thread safe in this code 
        mu.Lock()
        output = append(output, id)
        fmt.Printf(".") 
        mu.Unlock()
    case id := <-todo: -> **this will get called** 
        go concurrent(id, done, todo)
    }
}
```

}

https://play.golang.org/p/SmlSIUIF5jn -> I have made some modifications to make your code work as expected..

try referring this to get a better understanding of golang channels and goroutine

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1

Answer (score 1):

In absence of a `default` case, when multiple cases are ready, it executes one of them [at random](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5). It's not deterministic.

To make sure the case runs, you should run it in a separate goroutine. (In that case, you must synchronize accesses to the `output` variable).

Moreover you say "I would like to see every 100ms", but `time.After` sends on the channel only once.
To execute the case periodically, use `<-time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millis).C` instead.

```
    var mu sync.Mutex
    var output []int

    go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
        defer ticker.Stop()
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                 // TODO: must synchronize access
                 fmt.Printf("\nPolling status: %v\n", output)
            
            case <-timeout:
                return
            }
        }
    }()

loop:
    for {
        select {
        // other cases
    }
}
```